# How can I save the output of a python function that I run using a Tkinter button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I created a program that creates a heatmap from text files containing the x, y, z (z is always 0), and intensity values for each pixel in a 201 x 201 pixel area. I'm now trying to use Tkinter to create a GUI that will allow me to browse for a text file, and then display the heatmap for the file that I choose, but I'm running into a few issues. Here's the code that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk as ttk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
a.clear()

def Separate(image):
    '''Separate columns of text file into arrays'''
    img = np.loadtxt(image)
    intensity = np.array(image[:,0])
    x = np.array(image[:,1])
    y = np.array(image[:,2])
    z = np.array(image[:,3])
    return intensity, x, y, z

def constructImage(intensity, x, y):
    '''Create a heatmap of the data'''
    lenx = int(np.amax(x) - np.amin(x) + 1)
    leny = int(np.amax(y) - np.amin(y) + 1)
    intensity2 = intensity.reshape(lenx, leny)
    a.clear()
    a.imshow(intensity2, extent = (np.amin(x), np.amax(x), np.amin(y), np.amax(y)))

def SeparateandConstruct(image):
    img = np.loadtxt(image)
    intensity, x, y, z = Separate(img)
    constructImage(intensity, x, y)

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

def callback():
    '''Opens text file and runs Separate function'''
    name = askopenfilename()
    return name

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = ImageConstructor(container, self)
        self.frames[ImageConstructor] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(ImageConstructor)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

#Image Constructor Frame
class ImageConstructor(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        #Title Label
        label = ttk.Label(self, text="Image Constructor", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        #Button to browse for a text file
        browseButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Browse", command=callback)
        browseButton.pack()

        #Label displaying the path to the selected text file
        filePath = ttk.Label(self, text="No File Selected", font=LARGE_FONT)
        filePath.pack()

        #Button that creates an image of the selected text file
        constructButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Construct Image")
        constructButton.pack()

        #Canvas for the heatmap
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        #Button to close the program
        quitButton = ttk.Button(self, text="Quit", command=controller.destroy)
        quitButton.pack()

def main():
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The problem I'm having, is that I'm not sure how to save the output of the callback function after I use the browse button. I would like to have the filePath label update to display the file path to the selected text file and I also want to have the constructButton apply the SeparateandConstruct function to the text file that I choose, but I have no idea how to save the output of the callback function. Is there any way to save the output from a function to a variable if I run it using a tkinter button? I feel like this would be really easy to get working if I knew how to do that, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  One question per post please.

Comment: Oh, alright, sorry. The only question that I really care about at the moment is the first one.

Comment: @DarkDane in this case, please edit your post and remove the others...

Comment: You probably want `callback` to be a function of class `ImageConstructor` so you can write self.name = askopenfilename()

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short demo of how to make a callback modify a class instance attribute. The key idea is to make the callback a method of the class, so it can access the class's attributes.

Here I'm using it to update a `tk.StringVar` which is attached to the filename Label.

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        master = tk.Tk()
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        b = tk.Button(frame, text="Browse", command=self.getfilename_cb)
        b.pack()
        self.filename = tk.StringVar()
        self.filename.set("No File Selected")
        l = tk.Label(frame, textvariable=self.filename)
        l.pack()

        master.mainloop()

    def getfilename_cb(self):
        fname = askopenfilename()
        if fname:
            self.filename.set(fname)

Demo()
```